# Redirect Loop (HTTP_REFERER)

Tags: php, redirect

A web-site(*wwww.fake-web-site.com*) redirects its links to my web-site(*www.real-web-site.com*). Only the first page is different.

I wrote a code to redirect all people which come from the fake site to *google.com*.

```
if (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'],'fake-web-site.com') !== false)
  header('Location: http://www.google.com/search?q=real-web-site.com');
```

It works on Chrome browser, if someone opens the fake web-site and clicks on those links which are linked to my web-site, it will be redirected to *google.com*. After that he can open my site from *google.com*.

In Firefox, if someone opens the fake web-site and clicks on those links which are linked to my web-site, it will be redirected to *google.com*
after that, if he clicks on *real-web-site.com* in *google.com*, he redirects again to the *google.com*!

I think it's related to Firefox cache mechanism. Can someone give a suggestion?

Comment: This sounds a bit confusing. What are you trying to achieve? Do you want to atifically generate search requests looking for your page to fake popularity?

Comment: may be firefox caching header

Comment: @Mario: No, the fake page is attracting my customers, and its domain rank is better than me in search engines. I don't want those links to my web-site. If someone wants to visit the real site, he shouldn't find it from the fake site.

Comment: try to dump $_SERVER lets see what happen

Answer (score 0):

Browsers cache redirects. Depending on the HTTP response status:

If the status is *301 Moved Permanently* then the browser should and will (probably) cache it.

If the status is *302 Found* then the browser shouldn't and won't cache it.

Anything else is left to the browser to decide. From your code it seems like you're just responding with *200 OK*.

You can set a response header in PHP by doing e.g.:

```
header("HTTP/1.0 302 Found");
```

This has to be done *before* any other body or header output - unless you're using output buffering.

Comment: Interesting, let me try it.

Comment: Imho PHP is using 302 as default when using Location. To make sure the response is _really_ not being cached, explicitly forbid it in the HTTP header (see http://stackoverflow.com/a/2068407/413531)